# VBA based custom rule blocks receiving of incoming email or breaks graphical elements

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote below rule, which should under certain conditions (which are not hardcoded here) take incoming mail which contain important graphical elements and break all hyperlinks by manipulations on `.HTMLbody` and then send that email to another person.

```
Sub customRuleHiperlinkRemove2(MyMail As MailItem)
   'this block receiving of incoming mail
    Set currentEmail = MyMail

    currentEmail.To = "anotherPerson@xxx.xx"
    currentEmail.Subject = "newSubject"
    currentEmail.HTMLBody = Replace(currentEmail.HTMLBody, " href=", "")
    currentEmail.Send
    Set currentEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

but above code blocks receiving of MyMail message.

below code solves this problem, but on the other hand breaks all graphical elements included in incoming mail :

```
Sub customRuleHiperlinkTest1(MyMail As MailItem)
   'this breaks all graphical elements (do not copy them to new mail)
   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set newEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

   newEmail.HTMLBody = MyMail.HTMLBody
   newEmail.HTMLBody = Replace(currentEmail.HTMLBody, " href=", "")

   newEmail.To = "anotherPerson@xxx.xx"
   newEmail.Subject = "newSubject"
   newEmail.Send
   Set newEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

I could achive this manualy, by chooding forward on incoming message and then running macro which breaks links and then send that message, but is there programmatic solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Copy` method on `MyMail` solves the problem :

```
Sub customRuleHiperlinkRemove2(MyMail As MailItem)

   Set currentEmail = MyMail.Copy ' .Copy solves the problem

   currentEmail.To = "anotherPerson@xxx.xx"
   currentEmail.Subject = "newSubject"
   currentEmail.HTMLBody = Replace(currentEmail.HTMLBody, " href=", "")
   currentEmail.Send
   Set currentEmail = Nothing
```

End Sub